# binding a listview to a property of an object in a list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm a new to C# and I'm practicing my knowledge through WPF.. I'm trying to create an "EmployeeDatabase"

```
public EmployeeDB()
{
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "Hecbert Doval", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 14000 });
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "Harry Pottah", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 653000 });
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "Amino Vikola", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 230 });
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "Mila Spino", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 30000 });
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "Tila Tequila", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 90700 });
    _employeeList.Add(new EmployeeApp1.Employee() { Name = "TheRock Johnson", Email = "haloha@gmail.com", Salary = 14500 });
}
private List<Employee> _employeeList;
```

that uses a List of "Employee" objects and each of these Employee objects has "Name, Salary, email" as properties.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Next I created 3 listviews, arranged them to side by side, and each one should receive "Name" "Email" and "Salary" alone.

```
<ListView Name="lvName" Margin="20" Grid.Column="0" />
<ListView Name="lvEmail" Margin="20" Grid.Column="1" />
<ListView Name="lvSalary" Margin="20" Grid.Column="2" />
```

My question is how can I bind each ListView to the Name / Email/ Salary ? if it's possible.. if not any alternatives to achieve the same result ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why would you want three adjacent listviews, each displaying only one property?

By the way, are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? You should be.

Anyway, this is easy. First, expose `_employeeList`:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeeList
    = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList { get { return _employeeList; } }
```

Then, bind:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    Name="lvName"
    Margin="20" Grid.Column="0" 
    />

<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Email"
    Name="lvEmail"
    Margin="20" Grid.Column="1" 
    />

<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Salary"
    Name="lvSalary"
    Margin="20" Grid.Column="2" 
    />
```

If you'd rather do everything in codebehind, that's trivial to figure out for yourself given what I've shown you.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Thank you. Now to answer your question It's just that I'm trying to apply my knowledge step by step in WPF using real world application examples. This approach seemed reasonable to me (as a noobie) so I did it, if you know other ways feel free to suggest them to me I'd appreciate it. PS: I'm also planning to add textboxes on top of each ListView for the user to be able to insert the following data.

Comment: @cerberus23 Ordinarily you'd have all three fields shown as separate columns in the same listview/listbox/datagrid/whatever.